# iOS Dev via Xcode: UIView & UITextView/UIPickerView - Cannot Assign Delegate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, delegates, uitextview

Up until updating Xcode last night, this was working great (though probably through sheer dumb luck!).

I'm getting an error now for my UITextViews, Fields and UIPickerViews when assigning the delegate:

```
[m_textField setDelegate:GAMESTATE->glView.self];
```

m_textField is defined as UITextField*.  glView is defined as a UIView*.  To keep things simple, I'm using just one UIView for the entire app (could also be a problem).  I only need access to a couple of basic operations in the app to get simple text info from the user.  Now I get the error:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>' with an rvalue of type 'UIView*'
```

Like I said, I probably was doing something wrong in the first place, and it only worked through sheer, dumb luck!  If it helps, I'm already subclassing my UIView as an Accelerometer Delegate, as such:

```
@interface GLView : UIView <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
```

Any help, suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.  I've stumbled through some books this morning and brushed up on several Apple docs, but a quick work-around doesn't seem possible.  I'm not adverse to refactoring the way I take input from the user, I could just use a hand getting there.

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on their. What is GAMESTATE? And why are you calling .self on the glView. If you post more code or an outline of your app's structure, I think we can help more. What object is the delegate you want to use ?

Comment: GAMESTATE is a global singleton that I use - pretty poor way of passing a delegate around, I have to admit.  Nekto's suggestion below makes a lot more sense to me now that I look at it.  I've been skirting around proper implementation of iOS specific operations like this, but I really need to do it correctly from this point on.  Let me see if that will do the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create, for example, `NSObject` that will delegate

1. for `UITextView` : `UITextViewDelegate`.
2. for `UIPickerView` : `UIPickerViewDelegate`

Your class declaration should look like this:

```
@interface MyViewDelegator:NSObject<UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

Then you should alloc+init it and set it as delegator of your text/picker views:

```
MyViewDelegator *delegator = [[MyViewDelegator alloc] init];
[m_textField setDelegate:delegator];
```

Don't forget to implement appropriate methods in `MyViewDelegator` that are not optional for protocols.

Comment: Nekto, is it a good/bad idea to have one of these NSObject's that are subclasses of the respective view delegates (Picker/Text in this case) PER input field?  In other words, if I have 4 UITextView objects on a screen, should I have one of these MyViewDelegators per each, or all four should bind to one ViewDelegator?  What if there were 4 UITextViews on one screen, then another 8 on a screen later in the game - same deal with that, or different?

Comment: Keep in mind too, this isn't for an app - it's an entirely OpenGLES 3D game, with a very minimal bit of UIKit inputs.  I don't know if that would change the best practice or not...

Comment: UPDATE: I've implemented it (I think) correctly... but I am getting the exact same error still.  I have a new class, MyViewDelegator just like you suggested, I instantiate it, then try to assign it to the setDelegate, and no joy - same error.

Comment: I think that one delegator will be ok. But you should do as it is more convenient for you. The number of lines of code will be equal to both decisions. Try to use one object-delegator, for example, for two text fields and for other - create separate delegators (one2one). And you will understand what is more comfortable in your case.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense, Nekto, thanks for the tip!  I'm pleased to report (and embarrassed!) that it was an idiot's mistake causing the mess.  I still can't explain my my initial view wasn't working, but your solution does do the trick with a wrapper.  I was trying to assign a UITextView to a UITextField :)  Oops!  Thanks again!!

Comment: Remember, you don't HAVE to have separate objects to do this. Many people will use the containing view controller as the delegate.